# Выполнение консольной команды с помощью Python 3 (не видит команды)

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu, shell

[image: Выполняю вот такой код для получения и парсинга версий установленного окружения]
Выполняю вот такой код для получения и парсинга версий установленного окружения

```
import os
import re
import subprocess
print(re.search(r'[\d]*\.[\d]*', str(subprocess.check_output('lsb_release -d', shell=True))).group(0))
print(re.search(r'[\d]*\.[\d]*', str(subprocess.check_output('uname -r', shell=True))).group(0))
print(re.search(r'[\d]*\.[\d]*', str(subprocess.check_output('kvm -version', shell=True))).group(0))
print(re.search(r'[\d]*\.[\d]*\.[\d]*', str(subprocess.check_output('behave --version', shell=True))).group(0))
print(re.search(r'[\d]*\.[\d]*', str(subprocess.check_output('pip -V', shell=True))).group(0))
print(re.search(r'[\d]*\.[\d]*\.[\d]*', str(subprocess.check_output('appium -v', shell=True))).group(0))
print(re.search(r'[\d]*\.[\d]*\.[\d]*', str(subprocess.check_output('node -v', shell=True))).group(0))
print(re.search(r'[\d]*\.[\d]*\.[\d]*', str(subprocess.check_output('pyenv version', shell=True))).group(0))
print(re.search(r'[\d]*\.[\d]*\.[\d]*.[\d]*', str(subprocess.check_output('emulator -version', shell=True))).group(0))
```

[image: Получаю ошибку, мол pyenv не найден]
Получаю ошибку, мол pyenv не найден

```
/usr/bin/python3.6 /home/user/PycharmProjects/oc_mobile/update.py
18.04
4.15
2.11
1.2.6
9.0
1.9.0
8.10.0
/bin/sh: 1: pyenv: not found
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/PycharmProjects/oc_mobile/update.py", line 11, in <module>
    print(re.search(r'[\d]*\.[\d]*\.[\d]*', str(subprocess.check_output('pyenv version', shell=True))).group(0))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 336, in check_output
    **kwargs).stdout
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 418, in run
    output=stdout, stderr=stderr)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command 'pyenv version' returned non-zero exit status 127.

Process finished with exit code 1
```

[image: Но в самой консоли все нормально]
Но в самой консоли все нормально, с чем может быть связано? Ведь остальное выводится, кроме pyenv и emulator

**"type pyenv" выводит следующее:**

```
user@SMRPC0005:~$ type pyenv
pyenv — это функция
pyenv () 
{ 
    local command;
    command="${1:-}";
    if [ "$#" -gt 0 ]; then
        shift;
    fi;
    case "$command" in 
        rehash | shell)
            eval "$(pyenv "sh-$command" "$@")"
        ;;
        *)
            command pyenv "$command" "$@"
        ;;
    esac
}
```

Причем "echo $PATH" через стандартную линуксовую консоль выдает больше переменных, чем с помощью

```
print(subprocess.check_output('echo $PATH', shell=True))
```

**В консоли:**

```
user@SMRPC0005:~$ echo $PATH
/bin:/sbin:/home/user/.local/bin:/home/user/.pyenv/shims:/home/user/.pyenv/bin:/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/bin:/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1@global/bin:/home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/bin:/bin:/sbin:/home/user/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:$JAVA_HOME/bin:/snap/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/db/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin:/home/user/.rvm/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/db/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin:/home/user/Android/Sdk/emulator:/home/user/Android/Sdk/tools:/home/user/Android/Sdk/platform-tools:/home/user/Android/Sdk/build-tools:/home/user/.rvm/bin:/home/user/.rvm/bin
```

**Через питон:**

```
import subprocess
print(subprocess.check_output('echo $PATH', shell=True))
b'/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/bin:/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1@global/bin:/home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/bin:/bin:/sbin:/home/user/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:$JAVA_HOME/bin:/snap/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/db/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin:/home/user/.rvm/bin\n'
```

Так же не работает команда:

```
    import subprocess
    print(subprocess.check_output(['pyenv', 'version']))
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/lib/python3.6/code.py", line 91, in runcode
        exec(code, self.locals)
      File "<input>", line 2, in <module>
      File "/usr/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 336, in check_output
        **kwargs).stdout
      File "/usr/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 403, in run
        with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
      File "/usr/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 709, in __init__
        restore_signals, start_new_session)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 1344, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'pyenv': 'pyenv'
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: попробуйте проверить переменную `PATH` следующим образом: `print(subprocess.check_output('echo $PATH', shell=True))` - содержит ли она директорию, в которой находится `pyenv`?

Comment: если вы в консоли выполните: `type pyenv`, то что видно? (как текст вывод в вопрос добавьте). Попробуйте вообще без shell запустить (чтобы не думать о разнице между /bin/sh, bash, interactive/login shell -- какие начальные файлы читаются в этих разных случаях итд): `output = subprocess.check_output(['pyenv', 'version'])`

Comment: Добавил инфу по вопросам

Comment: Функция *pyenv()* не определена в дочернем subshell. Её необходимо каким-то образом передать (экспортировать?)...